# How do I display a number before the equations?

Tags: javascript

How would I modify this code so that when the equations are printed, a number is displayed before them. For example,

2x+1=12

-x+2=5

This is my code that i needed help to modify.

```js
function getrandomnumber(min, max, notthese) {
  num = min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
  return (num);
}

function getoption(s, ch, num) {
  var a = s.split(ch)
  return a[num - 1];
}

function getequation() {
  var num1 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num2 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num3 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num4 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var letter = getoption("x,y,z,w", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 4));

  var str = "" + num1 + "" + letter + "+" + num2 + "=" + num3 + "" + letter + "+" + num4 + ""
  var total = (num4 - num2) / (num1 - num3);
  return (str + " (" + total + ")");

}

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)


{

  document.write(getequation() + "<br>")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add the iterator `i` to your  `document.write(getequation()+"<br>")`

```js
function getrandomnumber(min, max, notthese) {
  num = min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
  return (num);
}
function getoption(s, ch, num) {
  var a = s.split(ch)
  return a[num - 1];
}
function getequation() {
  var num1 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num2 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num3 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num4 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var letter = getoption("x,y,z,w", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 4));
  var str = "" + num1 + "" + letter + "+" + num2 + "=" + num3 + "" + letter + "+" + num4 + ""
  var total = (num4 - num2) / (num1 - num3);
  return (str + " (" + total + ")");
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  document.write("<span>" + i + ": </span>" + getequation() + "<br />")
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px arial;
}
span {
  color: red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```js
function getrandomnumber(min, max, notthese) {
  num = min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
  return (num);
}

function getoption(s, ch, num) {
  var a = s.split(ch)
  return a[num - 1];
}

function getequation() {
  var num1 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num2 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num3 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var num4 = getrandomnumber(20, -20, "");
  var letter = getoption("x,y,z,w", ",", getrandomnumber(1, 4));

  var str = "" + i + ")" + num1 + "" + letter + "+" + num2 + "=" + num3 + "" + letter + "+" + num4 + ""
  var total = (num4 - num2) / (num1 - num3);
  return (str + " (" + total + ")");

}

for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)


{

  document.write(getequation() + "<br>")

}
```

Comment: did you take a look at my solution?